# Expect null and false rows linq

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq, nhibernate, activerecord

I have a database with structure like this:

```
id | name | approved
1  |  a   |    0 
2  |  b   |   null
3  |  c   |    1
```

I want to get the `null` approved row with this code (VB.NET):

```
Dim results = From j In ActiveRecordLinq.AsQueryable(Of Approval)()
              Where j.Approved = Nothing 
              Select j
```

But, the query returned 2 rows: `a` and `b`. Somehow when I expect only the row with `null` approved, the query also return rows with `0` or `False` approved. How the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the db field approved is BIT (Nullable), right?

if so, the generated entity (Approval) should have the corresponding property Approved of type  nullable boolean, right?

if that's the case, your query should be like:

```
Dim results = From j In ActiveRecordLinq.AsQueryable(Of Approval)()
          Where NOT j.Approved.HasValue
          Select j
```

Comment: I guess your generated object Approval is not very correct - the field Approved should be a nullable field, something like Boolean? or Nullable(of Boolean), can you confirm?

Comment: I declare the approved property like this: `<[Property]()> Public Overridable Property Approved() As Boolean`

Comment: that's the problem, the type should be Boolean?, or Nullable(Of Boolean)

Comment: Yeah thanks master, it's suppose `Nullable(Of Boolean)`. But, I still have problem to querying `False` value. My query like this: `Where j.Approved = False`. It return `null` value also.

Comment: Then you would have to do something like: 'Where j.Approved.HasValue andalso J.Approved.Value = False'